# How do I load a text file into an array and then delete an element? Java

Tags: java, arrays

I currently have a MemberList.txt file which I am using to contain the member's name, address, contact number etc. In the second field (separated by tabs) I have the member number which I am trying to find.
How can I load the text file into an array and then search the array for the second value of each member (ie array[i+1]) and compare the integer I'm given with the integer stored in that allocated space in memory.
I can post any relevant code which will help in answering this question, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post relevant code by default. Also give an example of the input file format. Is each data set given in individual lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any CSV parser that supports tab as a separator, for example Apache Commons CSV (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv) with CSVFormat.TDF (tab-delimited format):

```
File memberList = new File("/path/to/MemberList.txt");
CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(memberList, CSVFormat.TDF);
for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser) {
    int memberNum = Integer.parseInt(csvRecord.get(1)); 
    ...
}
```

And by the way it's not array[i+1], it's array[i][1].